# Pbreadcrumb DefaultMenuItem with a value from a .properties file (resource bundle)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a similar question like this: [DefaultMenuItem with a value from a .properties file (resource bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914562/defaultmenuitem-with-a-value-from-a-properties-file-resource-bundle)

I Upgraded to primefaces 5.0 and created a dynamic breadcrumb, but when i set the value of the key of my resourse bundle messages, is shown as a string like:

`#{message.label_register_document}`

but not the value inside on that key... in this case
 `label_register_document=registrar documento`
The expected behavior is that it should be shown `registrar documento` which is the value of the bundle message...

I tested with the static

```
<p:breadCrumb>
    <p:menuitem value="#{message.label_register_document}" url="#" />
    <p:menuitem value="#{message.label_register_category}" url="#" />        
</p:breadCrumb>
```

and it works as i expected. but when i set the value on the menu item like this:

`DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
        item.setValue("#{"+value+"}");
        item.setId(Integer.toString(this.migas.getElements().size()));
        item.setOnclick(ConstantesErp.FUNCION_STATUS);
        item.setCommand("#{"+action+"}");
        this.migas.addElement(item);`

where value is: `message.label_register_document`

does not work properly. Any suggestions?

P.S: Sorry for my english.

Comment: if anyone need the answer, i solved this and post the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914562/defaultmenuitem-with-a-value-from-a-properties-file-resource-bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer i solved by doing this:

```
public void addMiga(String action, String label) throws Exception {
    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
    item.setFragment(label);
    String valueTitulo = "";
    HtmlOutputText seccionLabel = new HtmlOutputText();
    if (label != null && !"".equals(label)) {
        String[] expresiones = label.split(",");
        for (String expresion : expresiones) {
            if (expresion.contains("label_")
                    || expresion.contains("_label")) {
                seccionLabel.setValueExpression("value",
                        getValueExpression(expresion));

            } else {
                seccionLabel.setValue(expresion);
            }
            valueTitulo += " " + (String) seccionLabel.getValue();
        }
    }
    item.setValue(valueTitulo);
    item.setId(Integer.toString(this.migas.getElements().size()));
    item.setOnclick(ConstantesErp.FUNCION_STATUS);
    item.setCommand(action);
    item.setAjax(false);
    this.migas.addElement(item);
}

    public static ValueExpression getValueExpression(String nombre) {
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Application app = fc.getApplication();
            ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
            ExpressionFactory factory = app.getExpressionFactory();
            ValueExpression ve = null;
            try {
                ve = factory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#" + "{" + nombre
                        + "}", String.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ve = null;
            }
            return ve;
        }
```